# Why this multiple criteria with INDEX MATCH is not working

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am following [this](https://exceljet.net/formulas/index-and-match-with-multiple-criteria) great article to practice INDEX MATCH with multiple criteria but the formula I wrote is not working. I am using the example provided in the article to practice (downloadable without signing up).

What is wrong with my forula?

```
=INDEX(Table1[Price], MATCH(1, ([@Item]=Table1[@Item]) *( [@Size] = Table1[@Size])*([@Color]=Table1[@Color]),0))
```

[image]

Comment: I know you've got an answer already but by just looking at the image you can see that your arrays are different sizes; columns B-D are only looking at a single row but column E is the entire table which is why it is unhappy

Comment: @RickyTillson good to note, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By inserting `@` for Table1 items for example `Table1[@Size]`, you are restricting it to only the row (row number) the formula is inserted while you are in reality trying to check the whole table. You should remove the `@` symbol. Your formula should be:

```
=INDEX(Table1[Price],MATCH(1, ([@Item]=Table1[Item]) * ([@Size] = Table1[Size]) * ([@Color]=Table1[Color]),0))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks but this didn't work, I tried various combinations with and without @ and you should have =INEX(Tabl1....not Table2 here since this is the source pickup table.

Comment: @zar Table2 was a typo mistake. But as seen on the image, it works.

Comment: Thanks that works. I recreated this issue at home PC and I realized my home version is not Office365 and that was an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on Excel 2016.

For anyone else that may have this issue....

The link that has those instructions on using this method says it's an array formula and requires Ctrl+Shift+Enter to use (see the Summary section from that link you gave).

Ref: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/how-to-correct-a-n-a-error-in-index-match-functions-f91874c9-d30b-4b7a-8a6b-c622764a1992

ps Your screenshot doesn't seem to show it as arrayed - its missing the {}.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1212638)